# Does changing the Primary DNS Suffix of a Windows Server 2012 machine require a reboot?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, windows, reverse-dns

My server has the following IP Addresses:

127.0.0.1

192.168.100.103

208.nnn.nnn.180

199.nnn.nnn.29

It's FQDN is mymachine.example.com.  However, calling `Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).HostName` only returns 'mymachine' and not the Fully Qualified Domain Name.  I'd like it to return the FQDN and have it in my head that if I can change the Primary DNS Suffix (from nothing to 'example.com') I'll be home free.

But this is a live running production server.  I don't want to make that change if it's going to cause a reboot.

Comment: Is this server part of an active directory domain?

Comment: No, it's standalone.  It's one of three and I'm strongly considering adding a DC for all of them for a few other reasons.  It would be a nice bonus if it solved this FQDN issue as well without having to change our source code and recompile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the primary DNS suffix of the computer does require a reboot. Changing a connection specific DNS suffix does not require a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the DNS suffix won't require a reboot, but are you referring to changing the search suffix or the "Suffix for this connection"?

I think what you are wanting to accomplish though won't be fixed by this...you are probably only getting the hostname and not the FQDN in your call.

Try this instead:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName
```

Comment: Changing System -> Computer Name/Domain Changes -> DNS Suffix and NetBIOS Computer name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of Dns.GetHostEntry("").  I tried it this morning but it just returns the machine name, not the FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

You might try one of the solutions presented at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804700/how-to-find-fqdn-of-local-machine-in-c-net) for getting the FQDN:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804700/how-to-find-fqdn-of-local-machine-in-c-net

Comment: Thanks Ben. I've been all through those solutions.  The biggest problem is that they all require modifying the code and rebuilding.  I'm trying to avoid having to do that if at all possible.